Zoom and pan an image at the same time
I’m trying to overlay two images (one background and one foreground with transparent background), adding a zoom and pan effect on each image at the same time. I was able to get the zoom part to work, and I can get some movement on the x axis with the x='x+0.5*1/a' expression, but I can’t control this movement. If I replace 0.5 by any other value the pan movement will have the same speed. Why?
Here is the full command:
ffmpeg -y -loglevel error \
-loop 1 -i foreground.png \
-loop 1 -i background.png \
-f lavfi -i anullsrc \
-filter_complex \
    "[0:v]scale=iw*5:ih*5, \
    zoompan=z='zoom+0.0005':x='x+5e-05*1/a':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125, \
    scale=1920:1080[fg]; \
    [1:v]scale=iw*5:ih*5, \
    zoompan=z='zoom+0.0003':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125, \
    scale=1920:1080[bg]; \
    [bg][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -t 5 -r 25 output.mp4


zoompan x moves center of zooming, try to move overlay → ...[bg][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2+5*n:...

@БаярГончикжапов thanks, I finally get the foreground to move! But is it possible to get a smooth and slow movement? With your expression, the foreground moves too fast, and if I replace "5" by 0.1 for instance, the foreground "jumps" (from pixel to pixel?). With the zoom I was able to upscale first and then downscale to avoid stuttering, can I do something similar here?

try to scale after overlay → [0]scale=8*iw...,zoompan...d=125[f];[1]scale=5*iw...,zoomp..d=125[b];[b][f]overla...,scale=1920:-2

@БаярГончикжапов yes I tried that, the foreground is still jumping.

I think, minimal smooth speed is 1*n, so you can't slow down that way. You can try to increase fps and/or scale → [0]fps=125,scale=10000:-2, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0003':x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1[f]; [1]fps=125,scale=10000:-2, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0003':x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1[b]; [b][f]overlay=n:0, scale=1280:720:flags=lanczos,framerate=25

@БаярГончикжапов I tried fps values up to 200 and scale values up to 20,000 (after that I get "non-zero exit status 3221226356" errors, I guess an out of memory error), and movement is now somewhat smooth but never slow! The foreground always travels at the same speed no matter the parameters I try.

I'm sorry, forgot about zoompan's size fps options. try → [0]scale=5120:-2, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0003':x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:s=5120x2880:fps=25*2[f]; [1]scale=5120:-2, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0003':x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:s=5120x2880:fps=25*2[b]; [b][f]overlay=n:0, scale=1280:720:flags=lanczos,framerate=25

@БаярГончикжапов even with s=10000x5625:fps=25*5 the x panning movement has the same speed. do you want me to upload my images somewhere so that you can test more easily?

I also removed the zooming from my command at the moment to focus on the panning:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i foreground.png -loop 1 -i background.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex [0]scale=10000:-2,zoompan=x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=2:s=10000x5625:fps=125[f];[1]scale=10000:-2,zoompan=x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=2:s=10000x5625:fps=125[b];[b][f]overlay=n:0,scale=1920:1080:flags=lanczos,framerate=25[v] -map [v] -c:v libx264 -t 2 -r 25 output.mp4

I was wrong. increase s and decrease fps to low speed (s=10000x5625:fps=25/3). but, it cause low speed for zooming also. if [0]scale=5120:-2, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0005':x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:s=12800x7200[f]; [1]scale=5120:-2, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0003':x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=1:s=12800x7200[b]; [b][f]overlay=n:0, scale=1280:720:flags=lanczos it has small jumping

@БаярГончикжапов thanks, I’ll take it! It’s smooth enough for me. To come back to my original question, is it also possible to add a pan movement on the background? overlay= only controls the foreground from what I see. If zoompan x controls the center of zooming, it should be possible to use it to control the background movement?

Hmm, tried to move zoompan x by this way→ [0]scale=6400:3600, zoompan=z='pzoom+0.0005':x='px-2':y='ih/2-ih/zoom/2':d=1:s=1280x720[f]; [1]scale=6400:3600, zoompan=z='max(1.1,pzoom+0.0003)':x='max(iw/2-iw/zoom/2,px+2)':y='ih/2-ih/zoom/2':d=1:s=1280x720[b]; [b][f]overlay

@БаярГончикжапов so we don’t use overlay anymore for panning? I thought you suggested this because x inside zoompan was not appropriate. I removed the z zoom movement for now to better see the pan, but this only gives me a pan on the foreground, not on the background (and foreground is stuttering): [0]scale=10000:-2, zoompan=x='px-1':y='ih/2-ih/zoom/2':d=1:s=1280x720[f]; [1]scale=10000:-2, zoompan=x='px+1':y='ih/2-ih/zoom/2':d=1:s=1280x720[b]; [b][f]overlay=n*3:0,scale=1280:720:flags=lanczos,framerate=25[v]

try without zoom and overlay, only background → [1]scale=6400:3600, zoompan=z='1.1':x='max(iw/2-iw/zoom/2,px+2)':y='ih/2-ih/zoom/2':d=1:s=1280x720
